# How to repeat one scenario in a feature file after it failed

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

Before my step definitions I do:

```
const {After} = require('cucumber');

After(env => {
    if (env.status === 'failed') {
        // Repeat env.scenario
        // {
        //      feature: [Feature],
        //      keyword: 'Scenario',
        //      lines: [ 4 ],
        //      name: 'Login for non-existent user',
        //      tags: [],
        //      uri: '/Users/ ... /features/test.feature',
        //      line: 4,
        //      description: undefined,
        //      steps: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
        // }
    }
});
```

Is there a possibility to repeat the single steps, or the complete scenario programmatically?

Something like

> cucumber ./features/test.feature:4

Comment: Did you solve it? Is it possible in Cucumber or not? I foud some JUnit @Rule solutions but Cucumber does not run JUnit rules.

Comment: No, I collect the failed tests after, and make a full retry with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option in cucumber. You could try something like:

https://martinholladay.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/a-better-retrylistener/

or

https://github.com/NetEase/arrow/blob/master/src/com/netease/qa/testng/TestngRetry.java